# resharper + VS Black theme makes Note: and TODO: Blue and hard to read

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I have a Black theme for the visual studio editor and it was ok until I've installed resharper. After this my TODO and Note text got really impossible to read, anybody knows a fix for that ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19094592/161457 - that worked for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can change your text and theme colors by just going to the Tools menu, and choosing Options --> Environment --> Font and Colors.

Look for the entry "Resharper Todo Item", and change it as needed.

Answer (score 4):

I use a black (well, dark blue) theme. You can change the ReSharper colour scheme in the same dialog as the Visual Studio colour scheme - in the 'R' section of the list, there's a bunch of 'ReSharper ...' settings.