# Change TODO item color in Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper-8.0

After installing Resharper 8 on Visual Studio 2012 my TODOs are now a retina-searing blue of which this screenshot does not do justice:

[image]

I've found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312785/todo-comment-font-color-in-vs2010-with-resharper-and-productivity-power-tools) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879284/resharper-vs-black-theme-makes-note-and-todo-blue-and-hard-to-read) they don't seem to apply to VS2012 and/or RS8, as there is no "Resharper Todo Item" nor any other Resharper items under the Display Items for Fonts & Colors.

Comment: This color is supposed to be ugly.  Then you're motivated to work on your *To Do* tasks so you can remove the comment.

Comment: Currently it's motivating me to create `TODOO`s and update my token list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Visual Studio crash and restart later, Resharper display items are suddenly showing up under fonts and colors. I contacted Jetbrains and apparently [this was a verified bug](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/26477768-ReSharper-Keyboard-Shortcuts-and-Fonts-Colors-do-not-appear-in-VS-after-installation), though that link is now dead which would lead me to believe that they fixed it, but for some reason this answer is still getting upvoted so maybe not.

Maybe the next upvoter can edit this answer or provide a comment with the current state of affairs?

Answer (score 25):

Just to post a possible workaround if somebody has the same behavior - apply actions from the [following article](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546479-ReSharper-Fonts-Colors-settings-do-not-appear-in-Visual-Studio-after-installation). It looks oddly but works.

1. Close all Visual Studio instances
2. Open C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VS
   version}\Common7\IDE\Extensions\extensions.configurationchanged file
3. Type anything there
4. Save the file
5. Open VS and check Fonts and Colors in Tools | Options | Environment

Comment: This solved it for me, submitted an edit to your answer to include the content of that bug fix. Note that you may need to open that config file as an Admin to edit it.

Comment: this solved it for me. Once I did this, I didn't have to go back into Fonts and Colors. When VS2013 rebooted, the correct TODO: color was back. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Navigate to environment settings using Visual Studio (Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors) and change the colour of the TODO items in the text editor. Scroll to the item in the "Display items" list which shows as "Resharper TODO item"

Comment: I can confirm that for me, there *is* a `ReSharper Todo Item` in the Fonts and Colors dialog box.

Comment: I have same issue as @joelmdev, the `Resharper TODO Item` does not appear under the `Text Editor` settings. I don't see any Resharper items under that category. However, some do show up under the `Printer` category, have no effect on the syntax highlighting of the text editor (obvious, but wanted to verify)

Comment: @Jarek see the selected answer (which is my own). This is a bug verified by Jetbrains. You can get the option back, however, at which point it shows up just as Rajesh has outlined.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Win 8.x issue; I am using Windows 7 and encountered the problem when I applied Resharper 8 to VS2013.  The link that Alexander posted resolved the problem for me.  I did, however, have to copy the file to My Documents, make my edit there (a simple hash symbol) and then copy it over the source location.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an empty line in the file extensions.configurationchanged worked for me.
Visual studio 2013 with Resharper 10